Divide data in x # rows and x # columns
I have 15,125 data points (all numeric) and I want to divide this data into a data frame with 125 rows and 121 columns. The data is order of which they should fall into those rows and columns. I haven't found a solution to accomplish this yet but figured there's probably something simple out there I'm missing.
As a small example, say my data consists of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 and I wanted to create  from this data 3 rows and 4 columns to get:
     Col1   Col2  Col3  Col4
Row1 1      4     7     10
Row2 2      5     8     11
Row3 3      6     9     12

Haven't really tried much as I haven't found a solution yet that would work. The data is loaded into R but I have no idea how to separate it all out into a table with certain number of rows and columns.

matrix(seq(12), nrow = 4) |> as.data.frame()
#>   V1 V2 V3
#> 1  1  5  9
#> 2  2  6 10
#> 3  3  7 11
#> 4  4  8 12

Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.0.2

You can make a matrix out of it using array (or matrix()) and convert as.data.frame.
> as.data.frame(array(x, dim=c(3, 4)))
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12

> as.data.frame(matrix(x, nrow=3))
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12

If you want a matrix, there's no need to use as.data.frame(), of course.

Data:
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)


That worked, thanks for the help!
